# ActiveRecord query for unique on a given column, given a certain order

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, activerecord

I have Events, with a date, and a name, that has_many Minutes

I need to find all the events that are the first one by date to have the given name, then collect all of the minutes associated with those events.

```
Event.order(date: :asc).uniq_by(&:name).map(&:minutes).flatten
```

almost works. except that I end up with an array, and not an ActiveRecord::Relation, and that I'd really like to start on Minute and make this into a scope like... Minute.first_time_events() gives me all the minutes from events that were the first event by date with their name.

One final caveat, I'm using rails 3.2. Thanks

Answer (score 1):

If you don't mind having raw sql in your app you could do it all in one call with

```
Minute.where(event_id: Event.joins(
  "INNER JOIN (SELECT url, MIN(date) AS minDate FROM events GROUP BY name) groupedEvents ON events.name = groupedEvents.name AND events.date = groupedEvents.minDate"
))
```

If you don't mind making two calls to the db then I would definitely go with the readability of Max's suggestion

```
ids = Event.order(date: :asc).uniq_by(&:name).map(&:id)
minutes = Minute.where(event_id: ids)
```

Comment: I was trying to avoid pulling all the events out of the database just for the `id` column.

Answer (score 0):

I would pull the `ids` of the events and then use that in a scope to fetch Minutes.

```
ids = Event.uniq(:name).order(date: :asc).ids
minutes = Minute.joins(:event).where(events: { id: ids })
```

The caveat here is that this is how I would do it in Rails 4. Some backporting may be necessary but you should really be focusing on updating your app since 3.2 will be EOL any day now.